# How to stop gunicorn properly

Tags: django, gunicorn, django-manage.py

I'm starting gunicorn with the Django command `python manage.py run_gunicorn`. How can I stop gunicorn properly?

Note: I have a semi-automated server deployment with fabric. Thus using something like `ps aux | grep gunicorn` to kill the process manually by pid is not an option.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

One option would be to use [`Supervisor`](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/examples/supervisor.conf) to manage Gunicorn.

Then again i don't see why you can't kill the process via `Fabric`.
Assuming you let Gunicorn [write a pid file](https://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html?highlight=pid#pidfile) you could easily read that file in a `Fabric` command.

Something like this should work:

```
run("kill `cat /path/to/your/file/gunicorn.pid`")
```

Answer (score 143):

To see the processes is `ps ax|grep gunicorn` and to stop gunicorn_django is `pkill gunicorn`.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, this is not an option (automated deployment).

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare do `kill -9 <pid number>`

Comment: htop is useful for viewing pids as well as sending various kill commands besides SIGKILL (-9)

Comment: Really, this answer is high voted? :o
It would stop all gunicorn instances running on the server :/

Comment: Doesn't stop it for me.

Answer (score 34):

```
pkill gunicorn
```

or

```
pkill -P1 gunicorn
```

should kill all running gunicorn processes

Comment: first one is enough.

Answer (score 19):

`pkill gunicorn` stops all gunicorn daemons. So if you are running multiple instances of gunicorn with different ports, try this shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
Port=5000
pid=`ps ax | grep gunicorn | grep $Port | awk '{split($0,a," "); print a[1]}' | head -n 1`
if [ -z "$pid" ]; then
  echo "no gunicorn deamon on port $Port"
else
  kill $pid
  echo "killed gunicorn deamon on port $Port"
fi
```

`ps ax | grep gunicorn | grep $Port` shows the daemons with specific port.

Comment: I had a similar case, i make this command: 

```
lsof "-i:${Port}" | grep gunicorn | cut -d" " -f2 | sort | head -1
```

Answer (score 17):

Here is the command which worked for me :

```
pkill -f gunicorn
```

It will kill any process with the name gunicorn

Comment: Works on Mac(zsh). Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Start:

```
gunicorn --pid PID_FILE APP:app
```

Stop:

```
kill $(cat PID_FILE)
```

The `--pid` flag of `gunicorn` requires a single parameter: a file where the process id will be stored. This file is also automatically deleted when the service is stopped.

I have used `PID_FILE` for simplicity but you should use something like `/tmp/MY_APP_PID` as file name.

If the PID file exists it means the service is running. If it is not there, the service is not running. To stop the service just kill it as mentioned.

You could also want to include the `--daemon` flag in order to detach the process from the current shell.

Comment: This is an elegant solution which garantees that we do not kill any gunicorn process accidentally. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

To start the service which is running on gunicorn

```
sudo systemctl enable myproject

sudo systemctl start myproject
```

or

```
sudo systemctl restart myproject
```

**But to stop the service running on gunicorn**

```
sudo systemctl stop myproject
```

to know more about python application hosting using gunicorn [please refer here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: This will work only if you created a `myproject.service` file in `/etc/systemd/system/`. See https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html on how to create systemd service files.

Answer (score 4):

If we run:

```bash
pkill gunicorn
```

We stop all gunicorn services, in this case to start gunicorn we only need to stop the parent process associated with the service that attends the port where gunicorn will be executed.

The following script searches for said process (pid), if it exists it kills this process:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# ---------------------
stop_unicorn_on_port() {
  pid=$(lsof -w -t -i "TCP:${1}" | head -1)
  if [ -z "${pid}" ]; then
    echo " no service deamon on port ${1}"
  else
    kill -9 "${pid}"
    echo " killed service deamon(${pid}) on port ${1}"
  fi
}
# Example/Testing
stop_unicorn_on_port 5000
stop_unicorn_on_port 5001
stop_unicorn_on_port 5002
```

##### more info check: `man lsoft`

- `-t` specifies that lsof should produce terse output with process identifiers only and no header - e.g., so
  that the output may be piped to kill(1).  -t selects the -w option.
- `-i`selects  the listing of files any of whose Internet address matches the address specified in i.  If no
  address is specified, this option selects the listing of all Internet and x.25 (HP-UX) network files...

```
Here are some sample addresses:

                     -i6 - IPv6 only
                     TCP:25 - TCP and port 25
                     @1.2.3.4 - Internet IPv4 host address 1.2.3.4
```

Answer (score 3):

```
kill -9 `ps -eo pid,command | grep 'gunicorn.*${moduleName:appName}' | grep -v grep | sort | head -1 | awk '{print $1}'`
```

`ps -eo pid,command` will only fetch process id, command and args out

`grep -v grep` to get rid of output like 'grep --color=auto xxx'

`sort | head -1` to do ascending sort and get first line

`awk '{print $1}'` to get pid back

One more thing you may need to pay attention to: Where gunicorn is installed and which one you're using?

Ubuntu 16 has gunicorn installed by default, the executable is gunicorn3 and located on /usr/bin/gunicorn3, and if you installed it by pip, it's located on /usr/local/bin/gunicorn. You would need to use `which gunicorn` and `gunicorn -v` to find out.

Answer (score 3):

The above solutions does not remove pid file when the process is killed.

```
cat <pid-file> | xargs kill -2
```

This solution reads pid file and send interrupt signal. This closes gunicorn properly and pid file is also removed.

PID file can be generated by

```
gunicorn --pid PID-FILE
```

or by adding the following in config file

```
pidfile = "pid_file"
```

Answer (score 3):

In your terminal, do:

```
ps ax|grep gunicorn
```

Then to kill the Gunicorn process, just do that:

```
kill -9 <gunicorn pid number>
```

In my case I dealt with many processes

For example: `kill -9 398 399 4225 4772`

Comment: This won't work as master process will create workers immediately if they are killed.

Comment: @tka, please stop your application or server if you've an interface like viscose and then, try again. It works well in my case. Otherwise you may selected the wrong `pid number`. Try also `pkill -f gunicorn`

Answer (score 0):

I built upon @David's recommendation to use --pid (PID_FILE) to fix the problem I faced because killing the parent pid didn't kill worker processes.

```
import os
import sys

import psutil


def stop_pid(pid):
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        p = psutil.Process(pid)
        p.terminate()  # or p.kill()
    else:
        os.system('kill -9 {0}'.format(pid))


def get_child_pids(ppid):
    pid_list = []
    for process in psutil.process_iter():
        _ppid = process.ppid()
        if _ppid == ppid:
            _pid = process.pid
            pid_list.append(_pid)
    return pid_list


def send_kill_cmd(ppid, cpids):
    stop_pid(ppid)  # Killing the parent proc first
    for pid in cpids:
        stop_pid(pid)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_pid = int(sys.argv[1])
    child_pids = get_child_pids(parent_pid)
    send_kill_cmd(parent_pid, child_pids)
```

Then finally excecuted above python script with below commands

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE_NAME=PID_FILE
if [ -f "$FILE_NAME" ]; then
    pypy stop_gunicorn.py "$(cat PID_FILE)"
    echo "killed -  $(cat PID_FILE) and it's child processes."
    sleep 2
fi

echo 'Starting gunicorn'
nohup gunicorn --workers 1 --bind 0.0.0.0:5050 app:app --thread 50 --worker-class eventlet --reload --pid PID_FILE > nohup_outs/nohup_process.out &
```

Answer (score 0):

`kill -9 $(ps ax | grep gunicorn |  awk '{print $1}')`

Answer (score 0):

I find that specifying the pid file location is the way to go.

```
$PIDFILE = '/var/etc' 
gunicorn master.wsgi:application  --pid $PIDFILE --bind=127.0.0.1:8090
```

A pid file will be created to the location upon running. Gunicorn will stop properly if you remove that pid file.