# Why can't I start my gunicorn server? "Connection in use"

Tags: gunicorn, ubuntu-14.04

Any ideas why my gunicorn server won't start?

```
jeffy@originaldjangster:~$ sudo /home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/bin/gunicorn -c /home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/gunicorn_config.py django_test.wsgi
 Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8001)
 Retrying in 1 second.
 Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8001)
 Retrying in 1 second.
 Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8001)
 Retrying in 1 second.
 Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8001)
 Retrying in 1 second.
 Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8001)
 Retrying in 1 second.
 Can't connect to ('127.0.0.1', 8001)
jeffy@originaldjangster:~$
```

nginx listens to `http://104.131.200.120/`, and passes to gunicorn, which listens to 127.0.0.1. I'm on Ubuntu 14.

I've listed all processes to see if gunicorn was already running:

```
jeffy@originaldjangster:~$ ps -a
   PID TTY          TIME CMD
  7653 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
 jeffy@originaldjangster:~$ ps
   PID TTY          TIME CMD
  7249 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
  7654 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
 jeffy@originaldjangster:~$ ps -A
   PID TTY          TIME CMD
     1 ?        00:00:02 init
     2 ?        00:00:00 kthreadd
     3 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/0
     5 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:0H
     6 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u2:0
     7 ?        00:00:00 rcu_sched
     8 ?        00:00:00 rcu_bh
     9 ?        00:00:00 migration/0
    10 ?        00:00:00 watchdog/0
    11 ?        00:00:00 khelper
    12 ?        00:00:00 kdevtmpfs
    13 ?        00:00:00 netns
    14 ?        00:00:00 writeback
    15 ?        00:00:00 kintegrityd
    16 ?        00:00:00 bioset
    17 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u3:0
    18 ?        00:00:00 kblockd
    19 ?        00:00:00 ata_sff
    20 ?        00:00:00 khubd
    21 ?        00:00:00 md
    22 ?        00:00:00 devfreq_wq
    23 ?        00:00:08 kworker/0:1
    24 ?        00:00:00 khungtaskd
    25 ?        00:00:00 kswapd0
    26 ?        00:00:00 ksmd
    27 ?        00:00:00 fsnotify_mark
    28 ?        00:00:00 ecryptfs-kthrea
    29 ?        00:00:00 crypto
    41 ?        00:00:00 kthrotld
    44 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_0
    45 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_1
    66 ?        00:00:00 deferwq
    67 ?        00:00:00 charger_manager
   120 ?        00:00:01 jbd2/vda-8
   121 ?        00:00:00 ext4-rsv-conver
   271 ?        00:00:00 upstart-udev-br
   275 ?        00:00:00 systemd-udevd
   322 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
   349 ?        00:00:00 kpsmoused
   351 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:2
   356 ?        00:00:00 systemd-logind
   358 ?        00:00:00 rsyslogd
   387 ?        00:00:00 kvm-irqfd-clean
   624 ?        00:00:00 upstart-file-br
   704 ?        00:00:00 upstart-socket-
   758 tty4     00:00:00 getty
   761 tty5     00:00:00 getty
   767 tty2     00:00:00 getty
   768 tty3     00:00:00 getty
   770 tty6     00:00:00 getty
   794 ?        00:00:00 sshd
   800 ?        00:00:00 acpid
   802 ?        00:00:00 cron
   804 ?        00:00:00 atd
   853 ?        00:00:01 postgres
   855 ?        00:00:00 postgres
   856 ?        00:00:01 postgres
   857 ?        00:00:01 postgres
   858 ?        00:00:02 postgres
   859 ?        00:00:02 postgres
   903 ?        00:00:17 supervisord
   961 tty1     00:00:00 getty
   982 ?        00:00:00 kauditd
  1266 ?        00:00:07 kworker/u2:1
  3027 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u3:1
  3230 ?        00:00:00 sudo
  3231 ?        00:00:01 gunicorn
  7014 ?        00:00:00 gunicorn
  7115 ?        00:00:00 sshd
  7192 ?        00:00:00 sshd
  7193 ?        00:00:00 sftp-server
  7200 ?        00:00:00 sshd
  7248 ?        00:00:00 sshd
  7249 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
  7610 ?        00:00:00 nginx
  7613 ?        00:00:00 nginx
  7614 ?        00:00:00 nginx
  7615 ?        00:00:00 nginx
  7616 ?        00:00:00 nginx
  7649 ?        00:00:00 sshd
  7650 ?        00:00:00 sshd
 7655 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

Here's the two gunicorn lines:

```
  3231 ?        00:00:01 gunicorn
  7014 ?        00:00:00 gunicorn
```

I've tried to kill those two processes, but when bringing them to the foreground with `fg 3231`, for example, it says "no such job".

Someone suggested I try `netstat -aWn --programs | grep 80`. Here is the result, which I don't understand

```
jeffy@originaldjangster:~$ sudo netstat -aWn --programs | grep 80
 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3231/python3.4
 unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8911     800/acpid           /var/run/acpid.socket
 unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    8908     800/acpid
```

Any ideas what is causing this "connection in use" error? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for "netstat -aWn --programs | grep 80" - saved me!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to `sudo kill 3231` and `sudo kill 7014`. I incorrectly thought they first needed to brought to the foreground. The fact that the processes couldn't be seen until I used the capital A option (`ps -A`) mislead me, that they were somehow special.

The server *was* running (in the foreground) when I went to sleep before my wife. She turned off the computer before going to bed.

Ubuntu and gunicorn Newbie. Could you tell?

Comment: i don't have `gunicorn` in the list when I use `ps -A`. But I'm getting the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Worked perfectly for me - accidentally closed the window my `heroku local web` was running in, but that apparently does NOT close `gunicorn`; this did the trick, and I'm back to making my webpages. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

I have gotten used to run `killall gunicorn` before (re)starting Gunicorn in my local development environment.

Answer (score 9):

I've found my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604653/how-to-stop-gunicorn-properly).

```
ps ax|grep gunicorn
>>> 932 pts/0    S      0:01 /home/someuser/flaskdir/.venv/bin/python3 /home/someuser/flaskdir/.venv/bin/gunicorn -w 3 flaskapp:app

kill -9 932
```

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who has nothing running on the port to kill, if `app.run()` is in the file gunicorn is running, then it will run twice on the port and keep attempting to retry the connection.

In my case, I was running $ gunicorn run:app where run.py had:
`from app import app`
`app.run(debug=True)`

in it. When I commented out the app.run, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
sudo fuser -k 8000/tcp
```

Answer (score 1):

**Restarting the computer helped for me**

- I did not have gunicorn in listing of `ps -A` so I did not know what to `kill`
- I also did not get anything obvious from `netstat -aWn --programs | grep 80`

Comment: Same problem in appengine standard env, runtime python37. Now how can we slove this

Answer (score -1):

I also came across same problem ... 
Dont try to run  gunicorn from **su** .
Just change user and try again