# Port 8080 not listening Gunicorn HTTP server

Tags: python, windows, google-cloud-platform

I installed my app dependencies using pip:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt --user
```

Then installed the Gunicorn HTTP server:

```
pip3 install gunicorn --user
```

but when I try  to run the Gunicorn HTTP server on GCP :

```
~/.local/bin/gunicorn -b :8080 main:app
```

I get the following error :

[image]

When  I try to check the port 8080 with cmd:

```
 -a -n -o | find "8080"
```

nothing shows up.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that nothing else is using port 8080?

Comment: @jdabtieu when I use  -a -n -o | find "8080" nothing shows up

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://amalgjose.com/2020/02/27/gunicorn-connection-in-use-0-0-0-0-8000. Try the netstat and ps commands first and if they don't show anything on port 8080 then sudo fuser -k 8080/tcp would probably work, as mentioned in the article

Comment: This might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230704/why-cant-i-start-my-gunicorn-server-connection-in-use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo fuser -k 8080/tcp
```

This will kill all the process accessing 8080 port. Then retry

Comment: I am using Windows OS