# Gunicorn process keep on forking until memmory is insufficient

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I have a nginx + gunicorn django application. Those process never die. For some reason until no-response:
[image]

Once it runs on local Windows 10 env - It works really good, no memory leak hangs.

I think local only "fork" (win dont fork IO know) one main, but why does gunicorn process never die?

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: check this first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14605047/7456750

Comment: https://newbedev.com/how-to-stop-gunicorn-properly

Comment: Ubunto 18 is the OS

Comment: I don't want to kill it I want it to be 2 process as "workers" is

Comment: what do you mean by saying never die? Do you want to stop the gunicorn process?

Comment: The issue is that it keep on forking the process over and over. until memory is insufficient.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232551/discussion-between-bryan-woo-and-flice-com).

Comment: When processes are colored green in htop, it means they're threads. Are you maybe spawning threads in your app?

Comment: I only use the django admin panel, so no threads I spawn.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was:

```
        if qs:
            print('sql:', qs.query)
            print('explain:', qs.explain())
```

This evaluate  all QS which is 2 millions raws ....
changed to:

```
        if qs.exists():
            print('sql:', qs.query)
            print('explain:', qs.explain())
```

solved the issue.