Coverage: How to gracefully stop a Django development server that runs on a Github Action Instance
I am testing some API endpoints of my Django app by running Playwright separately on a Ubuntu machine on my Github Action instance.
Since I also want to get the coverage of the tests, I am starting my server this way:
    - name: run backend server
      run: poetry run coverage run ./manage.py runserver --no-reload

This results in a single process being started.
Now, in order to collect the coverage data, I need to gracefully stop my django server, as force killing the process would also interrupt coverage and executing coverage combine would produce an error.
I have tried the following commands, but they all fail to stop the server
kill -SIGINT $DJANGO_PID
kill -SIGTERM $DJANGO_PI
pkill -f "./manage.py runserver"
python -c "import os; import signal; print(os.kill($DJANGO_PID, signal.SIGTERM))"

Is there a different approach I can use ? or maybe I am starting the server the wrong way?

Is there a specific reason it needs to be the development server? Can't you use gunicorn or something similar that you can gracefully stop using a TERM signal?

AFAIK there isn't. It just didn't cross my mind. I'll explore that idea

That was definitely the way to go. I got some help from this other question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604653/how-to-stop-gunicorn-properly
